# How to add column in DataFrame with value from another raw

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Dataframe:

```
    DATE        TIME    Value
0   20200103    100500  255
1   20200103    101000  356
2   20200103    101500  546
3   20200104    100500  652
4   20200104    101000  321
5   20200104    101500  632
```

And I want to recieve a new column according to the following rule:

X = Value where DATE == DATE and TIME == (TIME - 500)

**What I want to get:**

```
    DATE        TIME    Value   Х
0   20200103    100500  255     Nan
1   20200103    101000  356     255
2   20200103    101500  546     356
3   20200104    100500  652     Nan
4   20200104    101000  321     652
5   20200104    101500  632     321
```

**What I tried:**

The following code returns Nan values for all X:

```
df['X'] = df.query("DATE == DATE & TIME == (TIME - 500)").Value
```

Comment: The values in the TIME column contain duplicates. There are multiple candidates for choosing from VALUE where TIME = TIME - 500. The problem specification is unclear.

Comment: I think maybe @RustamM is refering with `DATE == DATE and TIME == (TIME - 500)` to actually: `DATE[i] == DATE[i-1] and TIME[i-1] == (TIME[i] - 500)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.where()`and `.shift()`:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df['X'] = np.where((df['DATE'] == df.shift(1)['DATE']) &
               (df['TIME'] == df.shift(1)['TIME'] + 500),
               df.shift(1)['Value'],
               np.nan)
df
```

Output:

```
    DATE        TIME    Value   X
0   20200103    100500  255     NaN
1   20200103    101000  356     255.0
2   20200103    101500  546     356.0
3   20200104    100500  652     NaN
4   20200104    101000  321     652.0
5   20200104    101500  632     321.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *boolean masking* along with [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
m = df['TIME'].sub(500).eq(df["TIME"].shift()) & df['DATE'].eq(df['DATE'].shift())
df['X'] = df['Value'].shift().mask(~m)
```

---

```
# print(df)
       DATE    TIME  Value      X
0  20200103  100500    255    NaN
1  20200103  101000    356  255.0
2  20200103  101500    546  356.0
3  20200104  100500    652    NaN
4  20200104  101000    321  652.0
5  20200104  101500    632  321.0
```